# In Django/South HOWTO create an instance of a model from a different app during DataMigration

Tags: django, instantiation, data-migration, django-south, generic-foreign-key

I need to perform a datamigration of a model **Answer** in app **Question**. In that script there is a dependency such that I need to create an instance of a model **Chapter** which is in the app **Journal**. So, I coded it as follows:

```
def forwards(self, orm):
    for answer_object in orm.Answer.objects.all():

        #This Works.
        blog, is_created = orm['blog.Post'].objects.get_or_create(title=answer_object.answer[:100])
        blog.save()

        #This DOES NOT work
        chapter, is_created = orm['journal.Chapter'].objects.get_or_create(content_object=blog)
        chapter.save()
        #cleanup task, not relevant to this question below
        answer_object.chapter_ptr = chapter
        answer_object.save()
```

But as expected this throws an error on " orm['journal.Chapter'].objects.get_or_create(content_object=blog)" saying that

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'content_object' into field.
```

This is presumably due to content_object being a GenericForeignKey so some operations are not allowed. But I also tried other alternatives for creating the "chapter" object like,

```
chapter = orm['journal.Chapter'](content_object=blog)
ERROR > TypeError: 'content_object' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

and

```
chapter = orm.journal.Chapter(content_object=blog)
 ERROR > AttributeError: The model 'journal' from the app 'questions' is not available in this migration. (Did you use orm.ModelName, not orm['app.ModelName']?)
```

So where am I going wrong? Any pointers appreciated. Thanks.

**UPDATE**

So since my earlier approach was failing I tried a new tack. The model whose instantiation was failing in my code *above* i.e. **Chapter** in the **Journal** app, I decided to create a datamigration for that instead. I also made sure to `--freeze` the models I am referring to in the `forwards` definition. Now this should have been straight forward, I would think. I have my forward code as follows -

```
def forwards(self, orm):

    for answer_object in orm['questions.Answer'].objects.all():

        #Works, AGAIN!
        blog, is_created = orm['blog.Post'].objects.get_or_create(title=answer_object.answer[:100])
        blog.save()

        # DOES NOT WORK, AGAIN!
        chapter = orm.Chapter(rank=1, content_object=blog)       
        chapter.save()
```

I would have thought that now since I am creating instance of a model (**Chapter**) which exists in the subject app (**Journal**) everything should have worked out. But i am getting the same error.

```
TypeError: 'content_object' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

It fails at the same point, namely, "content_object". I will post below the model definition  if that might help.

```
class Chapter(models.Model):

    rank = models.IntegerField()

    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey()
```

**UPDATE 2**
Wanted to add that all the models being touched in these forwards methods, namely - blog, chapter, questions; are fully defined in the 00n_*.py files created by South's schemamigration.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After getting help from Rob and folks on the South & Django user groups I was able to resolve this issue. Below is the definition of my `forwards` datamigration script.

```
def forwards(self, orm):

    for answer_object in orm['questions.Answer'].objects.all():


        blog, is_created = orm['blog.Post'].objects.get_or_create(title=answer_object.answer[:100])
        blog.save()

        #I have to manually lookup the content_type ans set it in the chapter creation.
        ct = orm['contenttypes.ContentType'].objects.get(app_label="blog", model="post")    
        chapter = orm.Chapter(rank=1, content_type=ct, object_id=blog.id)

        chapter.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

This has sort of been answered before here [Django South: Creating schemamigration for more than one app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166284/django-south-creating-schemamigration-for-more-than-one-app)

Basically south doesn't currently support multiple applications.

If you don't want to entangle your applications even more than they are, I would use raw SQL in a db.execute as a quick fix.

It looks like blog and journal are very inter-related. Are you sure you want them in separate applications?

Comment: But I am confused about why did it allow the "blog" instantiation, and not allow the "chapter" instantiation? 
Re: your question about putting blog & journal together - actually I watered down my example here for the sake of simplicity. There are other models like audio, image, video etc that can be in the journal. So I need to keep them separate.

Comment: Now that I think of it, I am not really migrating the other apps in my subject app. I am just creating new instances during the data-migration of the subject app.

Comment: The problem is that south only creates orm entries for the current application and some select django specific models (auth and sites for example).  You are referencing entities that don't exist in that .py file.  That's what the fabriate example in the other answer tries to rectify.

Comment: Hmmm. I think I am too tired to make sense of this. Sorry. I repeatedly get stuck at the point "it created blog, but it does not create chapter" part. Why such inconsistency? Maybe I am just misunderstanding something very basic here.

Comment: The basic misunderstanding is that South doesn't use your models.py definitions, it has the entire model expressed in the 000n_some_migration.py.  And it only has the current applications models plus a few from django such as auth, contenttypes, etc.

Comment: Rob, if you can kindly look at the Update I just posted & let me know what you think, that will be great, thanks for your time till now.

Answer (score 0):

In order to create a migration via manage.py, pass --freeze=other_app as arguments to add the models definitions of this other_app to the migration itself.

Answer (score 0):

This is a comment on Chantz's answer, which worked great for me (Don't have the rep to post this as a comment)

To save some others some time, you also need to freeze the contenttype app when you create your migration:

```
python manage.py datamigration yourapp migrationname --freeze contenttypes
```