# Instantiate new data on migration

Tags: django-models, django-south, django-orm

Suppose I have a model `Person`. Now I create a new model:

```
class Ranking(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    score= models.IntegerField(null=False, default= 100) 
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

The thing is, I want each `Person` to have at least one `Ranking`, so on creation of new Person objects I can just create a new `Ranking` for each object.

What I don't know is how to create a new default `Ranking` instance for each of the *existing* Person objects in the db?

In a django script it would look as simple as something like:

```
for person in people:
    Ranking(person=person).save()
```

Is there a way to add that code to the south forward migration file? Is there a better way of solving this problem? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, auto generate the migration `python manage.py schemamigration myapp --auto`.

Then find something that resembles the following in the migration file (presumably `myapp/migrations/00xx_auto__add__ranking.py`):

```
def forwards(self, orm):
    # Adding model 'Ranking'
    db.create_table(u'myapp_ranking', (
        (u'id', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.AutoField')(primary_key=True)),
        ('person', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey')(to=orm['myapp.Person'])),
        ('score', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.IntegerField')(default=100)),
        ('date_created', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.DateTimeField')(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)),
    ))
    db.send_create_signal(u'myapp', ['Ranking'])
```

After this, insert something like the following:

```
    # Create 'blank' Ranking entries for all extant Person objects
    for person in orm.Person.objects.all():
        orm.Ranking.objects.create(person=person)
```

Other approaches include splitting this into three migrations (this is better say if you have a large dataset in a production environment):

1. add the model, with the person field not required
2. add a separate data migration (`python manage.py datamigration myapp`), and insert into it code to do what I suggested above.
3. run the two migrations above (allow this to take time if necessary)
4. change the person field to be once it's all populated, and run this final migration

The [South docs](http://south.readthedocs.org) have [something along these lines](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part3.html#data-migrations). There's also a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976879/in-django-south-howto-create-an-instance-of-a-model-from-a-different-app-during) that might give insight.